# Suggested edit CSS bug

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, design, css

The right part is cut off (lines up with the sidebar from the main page).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. The change will be on live server after our next production build.

Comment: When is the next production build please as I am currently experiencing this?

Comment: @MichaelGrubey it's live, do you have still this bug? Could you give me your browser & os please?

Comment: Chrome - Version 33.0.1750.154 m and Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: This bug is [not fixed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/15Y9Y.png). FireFox 28.0, Windows 7

Comment: I also still see it occasionally -- not consistently, can't figure out what is causing it  -- in Chrome 34.x on Windows 7 & later 8.

Comment: Hey Stephane, could you take a look back at this when you get a chance? Definitely still happening...

Answer (score 3):

Very temporary fix:

- In your inspector, search the node with ID "suggested-edit-[some number]"
- In the styles for that node find class '.question-summary'
- Set its width to 100%